# Bug with ionic navbar

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Im building android app with ionic framework. I have a weird problem with my navbar.
I aligned my title to left(like all android app) using `align-title="left"`
But sometimes the in navbar , the title and goback icon are overlapping.
I made a codepen for this problem [HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/abudo)

You have to do these steps to see the problem

1. In homepage click Scientific Facts
2. Then click about in the tab
3. Again click home in tabs

There is also a problem with the transition when aligned right.
Any help appreciated

Comment: Can we meet and talk?

Comment: Where are you from ? Do you have the answer for my error ?

Comment: I removed `align-title="left"` but it align in center . But it will work for me .

Comment: Kindly share your contact details.As i'm also from Pathanamthitta it will be helpful in future.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a bug related to this. Can you try the nightly build and see if that works for you? I've seen issues related to the back button being shown/hidden and proper padding, but it should have been resolved.

You can include the CSS and JavaScript from these urls to load nightly build.

http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css
http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js

Navbar issue: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1858

Comment: will  the app work offline if i use online css and js  ?

Comment: It won't be able to load no, and you should not use the nightly build unless you are trying to troubleshoot something. I say this because if the bug is fixed in nightly, then you know the next release will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

After almost 2 years, ion-nav-bar is buggy as Harlem shake.

Seriously, going back to simple

```
<div class="bar bar-header">
```